# How can I measure in iOS app like the measurue app of Apple?

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS 12 there is default app of Apple called measure app . You can open the app, the frond end camera measures in Augmented Reality with a measure the distance between points.

I want to use the measure of the distance from point a to b (or multiple points) to draw a blueprint based on these measurements.

So I went to documentation of ARkit of Apple [ARKit doc Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit), but could not direct understand whether this was possible, neither in the forum of it. So i'd really like to know:

- 1 - How can I get the same result as in the measurement app?
- 2 - Is it possible to trigger the measurement app from my own app and
  get the result back to my own app?
- 3 - Which actual api's or documentation can be found about this
  topic?

Comment: https://mobile-ar.reality.news/how-to/arkit-101-measure-distance-between-two-points-horizontal-plane-augmented-reality-0185297/

https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/measure-using-arkit-ios-11-b21a36c2d379

Some tutorials that might help

Answer (score 0):

So in ARKit each `point` you move is 1 meter. example: `position.z = 0 -> position.z = 1` the distance in between is 1 meter.

When you place a node the world that node gets a z,y,x position. store these values.

You also have another position that can be reached, and thats your cameraPosition, if you move the worldPosition updates.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // Do something with the new transform
    let currentTransform = frame.camera.transform
    doSomething(with: currentTransform)
}
```

Now you can compare your node along with your cameraPosition and calculate the distance in between.

Your list:
1: Yes
2: No
3: Well, you have natasha robot, ray wenderlich and medium which is 3 sites that explain things really well. Check them out.

Comment: Could you recommend some stuffs to measure large distances with accurate results?

Comment: sorry, not without moving the phone / camera... Because the placement of nodes has to be close to the camera. But if you somehow manage to place the nodes in a far distance you just have to mutliply the vectors of the nodes and get the exact distance down to milimeter